# How Quantum Field Theory explains triboelectricity?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

in quantum field theory, do the materials also exchange electrons?

Comment: duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/412945/84967, by OP, now deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quantum framework is necessary when dealing with individual particles, atoms , molecules, even nano particles. Macroscopically for electricity and magnetism the classical theory works perfectly, and it emerges smoothly from the underlying quantum mechanical.

Quantum field theory is one of the quantum mechanical models used to calculate in the microworld of particles. In principle, everything can be described by quantum theory, including the quantum field theoretical model. But it is like using a surgeon's scalpel to dig the Suez canal to talk about triboelectricity in terms of quantum field theory and particle exchanges. The classical models are accurate and suffice.

> In quantum field theory, do the materials also exchange electrons?

All the elementary particles of [the standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) can participate in exchanges in a quantum field theoretical model , even composites of these, if there is a physics reason to use such a model. [Triboelectricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect) is described well by the [classical electromagnetic](http://www.electronicdesign.com/power/triboelectric-energy-harvesting-finally-gets-detailed-analytical-model) solutions.